# Match any combination of a group of strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a JavaScript regular expression that matches any number of a group of strings: for example, a regex that would match `onetwothreethreetwoone` or `twotwotwooneoneonethreeonetwo`. Is it possible to create a regular expression that matches any combination of the words "one", "two" and "three" in the above fashion?

Comment: Sure there is. What have you tried? Which language/tool are you using this in? Have you had a look at [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Comment: One possible use case for this would be checking the content of a string (to determine whether it contains only the allowed strings.)

Comment: What else could you possibly check for this condition than the contents of a string?

Comment: @m.buettner I could use it to check for combinations of whitespace characters in a string, and remove that combination if it precedes the first non-whitespace character. This is what I'm trying to do, specifically, but there may be many other use cases for this type of regex.

Comment: Yeah, um, okay. But unfortunately, that doesn't answer any of my questions from the first comment.

Comment: @m.buettner I have looked at the tutorial, but the answer still isn't obvious to me. I'll keep trying to find a solution.

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791282/regex-to-match-multiple-patterns-in-any-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). You might also want to use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) which ensure that the entire string is made up of this pattern. Then you can simply use Javascript's built-in `test` function to do the check:

```
if(/^(?:one|two|three)*$/.test(input))
    ...
```

If there has to be at least one of the terms (empty strings are not allowed) use `+` instead of `*`:

```
if(/^(?:one|two|three)+$/.test(input))
    ...
```

The `?:` suppresses [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and should always be used (unless you explicitly need capturing, of course). It's good practice and can considerably increase performance on more complex patterns.

If you want to find substrings of your input that conform to this pattern, omit the anchors (`^` and `$`), use the global flag `g` and use `match` on the string instead:

```
var matchArray = input.match(/(?:one|two|three)+/g);
```

Comment: Does this have any advantages over the other answer that was posted here?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I think I can safely say no. If you want to check an entire string for the pattern, then the other one doesn't even work as you expect (it would for example give `true` for the input `"fouronetwothreefive"` because it doesn't have anchors). it might also be a bit worse in performance due to the capturing group.

Comment: @AndersonGreen ^ and $ (beginning and end) are important if you need the whole string to follow the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(one|two|three)+/
```

Group is in parenthesis,`|` inside it stands for "or" and `+` means "one or more".